# Rails insertando un registro de otro modelo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, insert, model

Estoy tratndo de ingresar un registro utilizando un modelo, pero me arroja un error.

sponsors_controller.rb

```
def new
    @sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)
    @sponsor.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})
    @sponsor.assign_attributes({:pet_id => params[:mascot]})

    if (Sponsor.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:pet_id => params[:mascot]).count == 0)

        if (UserRole.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:role_id => Role.where(:name => 'Padrino').select("id")).select("id").count() == 0)           

            if UserRole.create!(:user_id => current_user.id,:role_id => Role.where(:name => 'Padrino').select("id"))

                if @sponsor.save
                    flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos "
                    redirect_to new_sponsor_gift_path(@sponsor)
                else
                    flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
                    redirect_to sponsors_path()
                end
            else
                flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
                redirect_to sponsors_path()
            end
        else
            if @sponsor.save
                flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos"
                redirect_to new_sponsor_gift_path(@sponsor)
            else
                flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
                redirect_to sponsors_path()
            end
        end
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Ya eres Pasdrino de esa Mascota"
        redirect_to sponsors_path()
    end
end
```

El error arrojado es el siguiente:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid at /sponsors/new
La validación falló: Role debe existir

Para dar una mejor visualización de lo que estoy haciendo o tratando de hacer tengo un usuario que va a ser sponsor de una mascota, pero una vez que el realiza esa accion automaticamente debe de registrarse que ahora tiene un rol llamado padrino que se hace en la tabla UserRoles, y que debo de hacerlo en el sponsor_controller en la accion new, teniendo en cuenta que ambos modelos no estan asociados de ninguna manera.

Gracias y espero su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error debe estar saliendo porque no encuentra el `Role` que estás especificando cuando creas un `UserRole`. Y esto no está incluido dentro de tu pregunta, pero hay varias cosas que mejoraría de tu código:

- Aunque sea posible hacer `@sponsor.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})`, lo adecuado es que simplemente escribas `@sponsor.user = current_user`, es la forma mas usada de asignar valores a tus objetos ActiveRecord.
- En vez de hacer `@sponsor.assign_attributes({:pet_id => params[:mascot]})`, deberías modificar tu form para que vaya incluido `mascot` dentro de los parámetros de `sponsor`, entonces con `@sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)` debería ser suficiente, sin necesidad de incluir la mencionada línea.
- Estás delegando demasiada responsabilidad al controlador que en realidad pertenece al modelo. Específicamente estás haciendo [validaciones](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) de modelo, como verificar que la dupla `user_id`/`pet_id` no se repita en la bd o que `user_role` para el usuario actual ya exista.
- Otros detalles, como que podrías usar [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) en vez de buscar y luego crear un registro o usar `Role.find_by_name('Padrino').id` en vez de `Role.where(:name => 'Padrino').select("id")` que te retornará una lista en vez del primero que te retornará el registro único.

El código final debería ser algo como sigue:

```
# tu modelo
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :pet_id, 
                                    message: "Ya eres Pasdrino de esa Mascota"
  validate :user_role_is_created

  # Esta lógica "sospecho" que le pertenece al modelo de `User`. Quizás poner 
  # en un callback `before_create` donde un `UserRole` sea creado cada vez que 
  # un user es creado, pero lo dejo a tu criterio.
  def user_role_is_created
    return if UserRole.find_or_create_by(
      user_id: user_id, role_id: Role.find_by_name('Padrino').id
    )

    errors.add(:base, "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota")
end

end


# método del controlador
def new
  @sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)
  @sponsor.user = current_user
  if @sponsor.save
    flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos "
    redirect_to new_sponsor_gift_path(@sponsor)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
    redirect_to sponsors_path
  end
end
```

Por último me llama la atención que hayas incluido la lógica de creación en tu action `new` en vez de `create`. Supongo habrás tenido tus razones, pero esto en general es desaconsejado y escapa de la metodología restful y de convención sobre configuración de rails.
Si lo que te describo no resuelve tu problema, agrega a tu pregunta el log de cuando creas un sponsor y el código de los modelos involucrados.

Comment: Hola acomodé lo usando el Rol de la forma en que mencionas en la solución y me funcionó, te comentó que traté de colocar la creacion en el create, pero no me deja hacerlo. En la edición coloco el index donde manejo esto. Gracias por la ayuda.